# Slide animation with UIView Transition?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewanimationtransition

I am setting a new navigation root. I want to show the animation when navigation is set. I am able to set the flip & curl animation with below code.

```
UIView.transition(with: self.window!, duration: 2, options: .transitionFlipFromLeft, animations: {
    let navController = UINavigationController()
    // App Theming
    navController.navigationBar.barTintColor = .white
    navController.navigationBar.tintColor = .white
    navController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
    navController.pushViewController(viewContoller, animated: true)
    self.window?.rootViewController = navController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}, completion: {_ in})
```

But, I need to set a slide animation from left to right for this. Can any body let me know how can I achieve this?

Comment: With UIView.transition, the only options are listed here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/animationoptions. Which consist of only flip and curl

Comment: So how can I give the animation when a new navigation is set

Comment: Perhaps just set a segue and change the segue "kind" to Show Detail? I'm currently setting the "kind" to "Show (e.g. Push)" and it's giving a slide animation of moving up.

Comment: If you see I am setting a new navigation here so I can't use segue

Comment: @Techiee do you care to look at the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fake a push on a new root view you could do something like this.

```
    let navController = UINavigationController()
    //App Theming
    navController.navigationBar.barTintColor = .white
    navController.navigationBar.tintColor = .white
    navController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
    //create our fake animation
    let trans = CATransition()
    trans.type = kCATransitionPush
    trans.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight
    trans.duration = 0.4
    self.window?.layer.add(trans, forKey: nil)
    //set your window change here
    self.window?.rootViewController = navController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Completely untested but I am pretty sure I have done this in the past at some point.  If that does not work try setting the rootViewController then adding the animation.